# sIFR 3 cut off uppercase charecters - work around?

Tags: flash, sifr, diacritics

I have been looking for help for hours now an I cannot solve my problem.
I have implemented sIFR3 in a website for headlines, but the uppercase characters such as "S" and "C" or special characters lieke "Ä" or "Ü" for example are cut off.

I found a workaround tutorial here:
http://blog.unity.fr/articles/sifr-accented-character-bug-fix-en
but there seems to be something wrong with my `sifr-config.js`

Now my text looks like:

```
<p class="accentfix"> </p><p class="sIFR-root">NEU: Partnerpreise</p>
```

And here is js:

```
css: ['.sIFR-root { ... }',
  '.accentfix{display:block; font-size:1; leading:5; }' ]
});
```

Hopefully there is someone who can help …

Best regards!

Comment: please see for results:
http://www.persiehl.com/persiehl/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tuneHeight` and `offsetTop` parameters to make the Flash movie a bit higher and move the text down. That doesn't work?